# Why there is no "cellular data" in iOS slide up menu?

Tags: usability, gui-design, ios

I'm frustrated how many times I have to go to settings > mobile data to turn on mobile data. If it were in slide up menu I would use it definitely more often than "do not disturb" or "portrait orientation lock". I can't believe there was a user testing that proved uselessness of that button in slide up menu. It is on Android slide down menu, so why there is no such option on iOS? Does anybody know the reasonable explanation?

Comment: Maybe it is not something that "normal" users tend to to do on a regular basis ?

Comment: Not acording to this statistics: [On average, U.S. wireless customers consume 1.8 GB of cellular data every month](http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2015/01/24/the-average-american-uses-this-much-wireless-data.aspx)

Comment: This seems like something you'd need to ask Apple. We would just be speculating.

Comment: It's a fairly normal requirement if say you operate at the edge of a wi-fi zone and use data hungry apps.  If you've turned mobile data off then you can't suddenly find you've used a lot of mobile data rather than wi-fi data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple is in the business of selling hardware, software and services of its own, and often hardware, software and services of others both directly and by proxy.

The early years of the iPhone saw Apple become the number one marketer and seller of AT&T services, including data.

Making and selling phone hardware requires a relationship with carriers to bring to market in ways consumers are most happy with. Apple wanted some unique provisions in their relationship with the carriers, starting with AT&T.

The services they sell by proxy (on behalf of service providers and content owners) they usually make deals around that give them more control over their hardware and software. Those deals involve compromise (often) on service provision lock-in and education. In the case of data, the telcos want the money from the use of data by Apple iPhone customers in exchange for the considerations Apple wants.

Apple made SWEEEET sweeet love to the telcos, singing their praises on data provision and telling them all about how Apple iPhone users would need more data for their new found love of browsing. In exchange (and amongst other things), Apple got the right to control things no other phone manufacturer has had before (or since), like firmware, operating system and integrated apps and voicemail operation.

Compromising on ease of access to shutting off data is one of the ways Apple negotiated these rights and the ability to update their phones without having to go through the carrier bloatware saga you see on all other phones.

Similarly, Apple made the relationship between the iPod and iTunes look difficult and cumbersome so users would be more likely to pay than copy. This helped them negotiate 99cents a song. Obscuring how to turn off only iPhone 3G/4G data wasn't the first time Apple's done this sort of thing to make a favourable deal for itself and its users.

Whilst Android posits more choice as one of its key benefits, one of those choices is waiting for updates whilst eat iteration of the OS goes through carrier additions of branding and software additions designed to encourage use of carrier facilities, for which the carriers charge and make money.